# Inserting values in LinkedHashMap without using the key

Tags: java, file, dictionary, collections, linkedhashmap

I have a table data in CSV format. First row contains all column names(keys) and all subsequent rows are records(values) as shown below:

```
ID,Name,Contact,Address
1,Alex,987654321,CA USA
2,Bob,4489398,LA USA
3,Marley,7236487,Washington
```

I am reading this file and trying to store the records as key value pair in LinkedHashMap. Here is my code to show what I am trying to do. My question is written in the code as comment.

```
public static void readCSV() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("table.csv"));

    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    String line = br.readLine();
    String[] keys = line.split(",");

    /*insert all keys with a corresponding empty arraylist as value to store
    all values of a particular key. ie each arralist will contain all values
    of individual columns. Since it is a linkedhashmap, keys are stored in 
    same order as they appear in the csv file*/

    for (String key : keys) {
        map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        String[] values = line.split(",");

        for (String value : values) {

            /*here I want to get the arraylists sequentially to store value.
            I know the first value goes in the first arraylist, second goes
            to second arraylist and so on.

            Is there a way to do this without using the key here??
            */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this data structure and not a map key -> columnIndex and a list of `String[]` (one per row)?

Comment: It could be better to parse every row to a custom object and put them into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `Iterator` to iterate over the values of your `Map` :

```
while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
    String[] values = line.split(",");

    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> iter = map.values().iterator ();
    for (String value : values) {

        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            iter.next().add(value);
        }

    }
}
```